# How does Keras (Tensorflow) compute gradients over batches in custom loss functions?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Under the hood, is a single gradient computed with respect to the whole batch, or is it the mean of gradients for each training pair? I'm writing a custom loss function and would like to include a loss component that is a function of the aggregate statistics over the batch. I'm wondering if this is consistent with the framework.  My actual use case is complicated, but as an example, consider that I want my loss function to be whether the categories are correct (dog or cat) plus a term pushing for a 50/50 split between dog and cats in the batch.  It's easy enough to program this into the loss function, but will the gradients do the right thing?

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable/confident enough to post this as an answer, but yes, what you have in mind will work.

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me.  your custom loss will have a signature like custom_loss(yTrue, yPred). So what you are describing you want to count the diffs between yTrue and yPred+  f(yPred), where f is the function which generates your extra term from the yPred?

Comment: In my case I'm not doing a fit or classification where there's an actual yTrue.  I have a loss that is a function of yPred alone - similar to triplet loss in a siamese network.  The distinction is that I want a term that is a function of all the yPred in the batch, not just one. yPred is of size yPred(batch_size, n), I'd like to compute some terms across the batch dimension.